# Add and Delete query using Postgres

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm trying to create 3 pages that are connected to each other.

*Requests page
Deleted page
Page Accepted*

Which in the database correspond to:

*prenotaziones
prenotazioneAccettate
prenotazioneCancellate*

When a user completes the form fields, the entry is made in "Request Page". And from here the requests can be accepted or rejected. And every time a request is accepted or rejected, it is deleted from "Request Page".

Now the problem is that while in mysql all this process worked perfectly to me, on postgres instead the only thing that my code does is delete from "Requests" and not insert anything on the other pages.

This is the code:

```
 <td>
        <a href="prenotazioniRichieste.php?delete=<?php echo $id; ?>"onclick="return confirm ('Are you sure?');"><img src="image/cross.png"></a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="prenotazioniRichieste.php?accept=<?php echo $id; ?>"onclick="return confirm ('Are you sure?');"><img src="image/check.png"></a>
    </td>

    </tr>

    <?php
     $i++;
    }
    if(isset($_GET['delete'])){
           $delete_id = $_GET['delete'];
        //   mysqli_query($dbh,"INSERT INTO PrenotazioneCancellate SELECT * FROM Prenotazione WHERE id='$delete_id'");
        //   mysqli__query($dbh,"DELETE FROM prenotaziones WHERE id='$delete_id'");
        // header("location: prenotazioniRichieste.php");


        $sqld1 = "INSERT INTO prenotazioneCancellate SELECT * FROM prenotaziones WHERE id='$delete_id'";
            $resultd1 = $dbh->prepare($sqld1);
            $resultd1->execute();
        $sqld2 = "DELETE FROM prenotaziones WHERE id='$delete_id'";
            $resultd2 = $dbh->prepare($sqld2);
            $resultd2->execute();

    }

    if(isset($_GET['accept'])){
           $accept_id = $_GET['accept'];
       //    mysqli_query($dbh,"INSERT INTO PrenotazioneAccettate SELECT * FROM Prenotazione WHERE id='$accept_id'");
       //    mysqli_query($dbh,"DELETE FROM Prenotazione WHERE id='$accept_id'");
       //    header("location: prenotazioniRichieste.php");
        $sqla1 = "INSERT INTO PrenotazioneAccettate SELECT * FROM prenotaziones WHERE id='$accept_id'";
            $resulta1 = $dbh->prepare($sqla1);
            $resulta1->execute();
        $sqla2 = "DELETE FROM prenotaziones WHERE id='$accept_id'";
            $resulta2 = $dbh->prepare($sqla2);
            $resulta2->execute();
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: you should have a look into your postgres error log. I think problem lies within capital letters of tablenames. try \"PrenotazioneAccettate\" instead PrenotazioneAccettate and \"prenotazioneCancellate\".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change would be :

```
$sqld1 = "INSERT INTO \"prenotazioneCancellate\" SELECT * FROM prenotaziones WHERE id='$delete_id'";
```

second would be (if you use PDO and prepared statements and dont want to worry about variables and sql-injections):

```
 $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO public.\"prenotazioneCancellate\" 
                  SELECT * FROM public.prenotaziones 
              WHERE public.prenotaziones.id=:id_to_delete";
 $loStatement = $dbh->prepare($sqlQuery);
 $loStatement->bindValue(':id_to_delete', $delete_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $loStatement->execute();
 $loResult = loStatement->fetchAll();
```

in postgres your database can be spread up in schematas. thats e.g. public. you can use tables with upper letters but have to escape them in the correct way.
Your deletes work, cause the tablename are always in lower letters: prenotaziones

and the last one:

```
try {
   $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO public.\"prenotazioneCancellate\" 
                      SELECT * FROM public.prenotaziones 
                  WHERE public.prenotaziones.id=:id_to_delete";
   $loStatement = $dbh->prepare($sqlQuery);
   $loStatement->bindValue(':id_to_delete', $delete_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $loStatement->execute();
   $loResult = loStatement->fetchAll();
}
catch(Exception $e) {
//do something with the error
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! :)